# Responsive top banner icons

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, responsive

I am relatively new to wordpress so please do forgive any incorrect terminology or silly questions as I am still learning and eager to do so.

I have a jewellery website (running Kallyas premium) which I have a row of banner icons inbetween the header and rev slider.

**top banner icons**
[image: top banner icons]

The problem is when viewing the site on reduced screen size or mobile view I want to replace this row of icons with one single icon/slider which displays my banner icons one at a time eg. Lowest Prices, A* customer service so on and so on.

A good example of what I'm trying to achieve is on the Watchshop.com homepage when viewed in mobile view.

**watchshop.com slider effect**
[image: watchshop.com slider effect]

I can't seem to find a plugin that does this and I can't seem to achieve this with rev slider, maybe it needs some code?

Any help will be gratefully received.

Thanks
Dan

Comment: StackOverflow is for broken code.

Comment: I can tell that you have no HTML or CSS experience. Please read about them, then learn responsive styling (CSS media queries) if you want to create changes. Otherwise ask the developer of your template.

Comment: Sorry isn't this supposed to be a help forum?

Comment: Sorry @dan2017 but I think wordpress takes care of these things if you are using a very responsive theme, try look for one and apply it

Comment: @dan2017 it's a help forum for developers who cannot figure out why their code fails. It's not a general purpose wordpress support forum (but they have those at wordpress.org).

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

you would need to add some css media querys to show and hide certain things depending on screen size, for example you want to hide the nav links at mobile:

try something like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.your_class_her_or_id_here {
        display:none;
        }
    }
```

this would hide the nav links when viewed at screen size less than 768px, 
you could do the same for the slider, so it only shows at a certain size otherwise its not shown. Hope this helps.